# Installing canon pixma mg5650 in linux ubuntu

Tags: canon, pixma

I have just bought a whole new canon pixma mg5650, and I am having difficulties installing it with my ubuntu operative system.

Can anyone tell me how to connect my printer to the computer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That exact printer does not exist on the official Canon USA support page but you could try going to [the official Canon support page for the apparently similar MG5620 printer](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg5620?selectedName=DriversAndSoftware) and downloading the Linux drivers.  These drivers appear to be the same ones Canon supplies for my Maxify 2300 printer, which works well with Ubuntu.  I think there is a fair chance they will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model and just installed "MG5500 series IJ Printer Driver Ver. 4.00 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)" from here
http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100550602.html on Ubuntu 15.10 64bit. Just unpack, run "install.sh", connect the printer to the network and it should appear as "Other printers detected" when the installer scans the network. Just enter the number (e.g. 101), let the installer register the printer and you should be able to use it for printing purposes (I have not yet checked for scanner support).

Good luck!